# Can't able to play IPTV channel in Flutter Video Player

Tags: flutter, m3u8, m3u, flutter-video-player, iptv

I have made a flutter video player app and want to play IPTV channel in the app. The player is playing some online videos successfully but it is not able to run the link of IPTV.
I have a paid IPTV m3u playlist file. I want to play the specific channel of the list in the video player. I have extracted the link from the m3u file and pasted in the player but its not working.
The link is looks like this(http://ottbest.net:80/940F4D6ACD4F/4A30606C8931/83137). This link is running successfully in VLC and MX Player.

Answer (score 0):

First extract your m3u playlist to dart object using [m3u_nullsafe](https://pub.dev/packages/m3u_nullsafe) package.
Then, you can use [Flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player) to play m3u videos

Comment: Would be great if you could provide ome working example code.